# Creating sgplot-like discrete heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I would like to create a heatmap in R that resembles output from SAS's proc sgplot like below.

[image]

The best I could do was

```
set.seed(1)
testdat <- data.frame(reader= c(rep(c("reader1","reader2","reader3"),each=6)),
                      case= c(rep(c("Case1","Case1","Case2","Case2","Case3","Case3"),3)),
                      q=c(rep(c("Q3","Q4"),18)),
                      value=ordered(sample(1:5,18,replace=T)))

> head(testdat,7)
   reader  case  q value
1 reader1 Case1 Q3     1
2 reader1 Case1 Q4     4
3 reader1 Case2 Q3     1
4 reader1 Case2 Q4     2
5 reader1 Case3 Q3     5
6 reader1 Case3 Q4     3
7 reader2 Case1 Q3     2
```

with ggplot

```
library(ggplot)
testheat <- ggplot(testdat, aes(q,reader,fill=value,label=q)) +
  geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap(~case,scales="fixed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","lightgreen","green","indianred1","red")) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

to create

[image]

which... doesn't really look impressive.  What can I do to make the heatmap look like a sgplot output?

Comment: You're asking how to make this plot look "impressive"? What exactly does that mean? What specifically do you want to change to make it look more like `sgplot`?

Comment: I should be more specified as you said. The most noticeable difference I observe is the header and the boundary that separates the tiles.  The tile size seems to be bulkier, but altering the size within geom_tile() doesn't seem to "collapse" the axis.

But mostly, I was hoping there is maybe an easier way than modifying ggplot individually (maybe a theme? another package?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat cleaned up version. I used `facet_grid` not `facet_wrap` to combine the y scales. Picked a nicely curated color scale. Removed the unnecessary axis labels. Added a `color` to `geom_tile` to make the lines. Used a more minimal theme. Changed the size of the plot window so it's more compact (this is just resizing the window with the mouse - if you save the plot you can specify whatever dimensions you want).

```
ggplot(testdat, aes(q,reader,fill=value,label=q)) +
  geom_tile(color = "gray60") +
  facet_grid(~case) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "RdYlGn", direction = -1) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
  ggthemes::theme_clean() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Looks amazing, especially with your theme choice making it look closer to sgplot output.  Adding + theme(strip.placement = "outside") on yours made it look very desirable.

Comment: `theme_minimal()` also looks nice.